# How is MIDI File Playback Handled in General?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, playback, midi

I'm programming an android app involving MIDI file playback. I want to use Android's dynamic callback method to visualize the sound waves, which looks something like this:

```
 mVisualizer.setDataCaptureListener(new Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener() {
        public void onWaveFormDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes,
                int samplingRate) {
            mVisualizerView.updateVisualizer(bytes);
        }

        public void onFftDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes, int samplingRate) {}
    }, Visualizer.getMaxCaptureRate() / 2, true, false);
}
```

I understand the bit depth and sampling rate are the two parameters used by computer to record/playback audio, but does this also apply to the MIDI file format? As I've read, other file formats such as mp3 and wav contain the "actual" audio information, but MIDI only contains instructions and the audio is created only when a MIDI file is being played. So will I still be able to get the waveform playback parameters if I were to play a MIDI file instead of, say, a mp3 file?

Comment: I'm sure you can find information regarding the MIDI standard in many places on the internet. But simply put, you are correct: MIDI consists of instructions, that are ordered in time sequence, that specify what notes are to go on or off at various times, as well as other expression instructions, etc. It doesn't contain any wave or note quality content. That's the job of a tone generator or MIDI interpreter. Most sound cards have built-in tone generators. There is no "waveform" information in MIDI.

Comment: But do you know if the waveform information will be generated by the MIDI interpreter when the playback takes place?

Comment: At some point a waveform has to be generated, but it probably isn't captured. There are ways to capture it, though. In some cases, some sound software might support generating a WAV file from MIDI using the capabilities of the sound card. I have also played MIDI with a sound card and captured it with the record in of the sound card (or it may have been with a 2nd sound card, I don't recall - a long time ago).

Comment: It worked! XD I just tested it out, and I did get the waveform data callbacks from the MIDI playback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So yes! Sound wave will be captured regardless of audio format.